# How to check whether my locationManager object is configured with standard location updates or significant location updates?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

In my app, I am trying to change the type of location service which is configured with locationManager object i.e. standard location updates or significant location changes. So I need some way to check whether my locationManager object is configured with standard location updates or significant location updates?

Any help will be much appreciated :)

Comment: Please include anything you have tried or any error you are facing. Will help us more knowing what you have done.

Comment: I implemented standard location updates and they are working fine, the case now is my app is having one switch to change the location service from standard to significant. So after changing location service I  need some way to check with what my locationManager is configured with.

Comment: But your code is the thing setting the location manager mode, so your code already knows what the mode is.

Comment: ya that's correct i know my code only is setting which location service it wants to use. But my point here is, there should be some way for checking what mode it is operating on.